# ATL Web service Logging

Tags: c++, web-services, iis, logging, atl

I have created a c++ ATL web service in visual studio 2005. I want to have detailed logs for my web service as what request come or weather any exception happened during the Database call.

I am hosting my web service through IIS. I know that IIS create a log file if logging is enabled But i want to have some more control over those logs in terms of format.

Is there any method to use IIS system itself to implement our own logs inside that log file or 
Should I implement a multithreaded logging system which will push logs to a text file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want logging beyond what IIS offers natively, you will either have to implement your own logger or make use of any of dozens of loggers already out there.

One that a lot of people love is Peantheios: http://www.pantheios.org/

There are many out there.

The simple answer to your question, though, is that IIS does not have built-in facilities for logging beyond what you see in the GUI.